# cannot launch Jupyter from anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just got a new laptop at work and installed anaconda.. howerver, when i launched Jupyter I received the following error. Does anyone know what i should do here? Cheers

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 9, in 
import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\darren.chapman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 12, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Comment: I guess you did not add Anaconda to PATH? If that is so, either add it to PATH or uninstall, while reinstalling check the option where it asks to add Anaconda to PATH.

Comment: What version of the Anaconda did you install?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for taking the time to respond. I installed Python 3.7 version and I did check the add anaconda to path box. m'mmm strange.. any other suggestions? cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path.

while installing click the add anoconda to the path.

Comment: I did that.. any other ideas? Cheers